# How to resolve "error: cannot find symbol" in Java?

Tags: java

```
public void sort(){

 Node sortedList = null;

   while(sortedList != null){

    Node current = sortedList;
    sortedList = sortedList.next;
    Node x;
    Node previous = null;
    for(x = sortedList; x != null; x = x.next){
        if(current.value < x.value){
                break;
         }
         previous = x;
    }
    if(previous == null){               
          current.next = sortedList;
          sortedList = current;
    }
    else{               
       current.next = previous.next;
       previous.next = current;
    }

  return sortedList;
}}}
```

this is the error message:

```
LinkedList.java:352: error: cannot find symbol
if(current.value < x.value){
           ^
symbol: variable value
location: variable current of type `LinkedList.Node`
```

Comment: this is the error message                                                    LinkedList.java:352: error: cannot find symbol
        if(current.value < x.value){
                  ^
  symbol:   variable value
  location: variable current of type LinkedList.Node

Comment: it would seem there is no variable with the name value accessible in the class Node

Comment: show us the definition of `Node`

Answer (score 1):

It's because return type of method `sort()` is `void` but you are trying to return value from `sort()`

```
return sortedList;
```

Looking at your code, I suppose you might want to declare it as:

```
public Node sort()
```

*Additional note:* Code snippet that you posted, seems to have additional closing braces `}`. You might need to look for that as well.